# How to check if a domain is "alive" or "parked" from command line?

Tags: command-line, domain-name

If some domain name becomes stale, it usually still replies to HTTP requests with some bunches of useless links, sometimes even without an explicit "This domain is expired/for sale" message instead of just failing to resolve at all.

How to automatically determine the "dead" (expired/not prolonged) domain without a browser? Can it be done with `whois` tool?

Expecting something like this:

```
while true; do
    if ! checkdomain something-on-verge-of-abandoning-business.com; then
        echo "Good night, sweet prince"
        break
    fi
    sleep 1d
done
```

For example, let's look at domain `allmydata.com`. As far as I see about Allmydata, there should be some Tahoe-LAFS-based backup service there. But actually it is parked domain.

```
$ whois allmydata.com
...
   Domain Name: ALLMYDATA.COM
   Registrar: DOMAIN MONKEYS, LLC
   Whois Server: whois.domainmonkeys.com
   Referral URL: http://www.domainmonkeys.com
   Name Server: NS1.DSREDIRECTION.COM
   Name Server: NS2.DSREDIRECTION.COM
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Updated Date: 04-aug-2013
   Creation Date: 03-aug-2004
   Expiration Date: 03-aug-2014
...

$ dig +short -t A allmydata.com @8.8.8.8
208.73.211.247
```

This shallow check shows like it is were a good domain. But how to reliably (i.e. not heuristically parsing the page and measuring "spammy-ness" or "parked-ness" from content) detect such thing?

Comment: linux I assume?

Comment: For example, GNU/Linux. But I expect the approach to be portable.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use python to read in the html content and then search for "domain available"/"parked"/"renewal" etc and other keywords. You can feed it a CSV file of domains and then output the results as CSV and there you have a list of domains.

The other idea would be to parse whois records using something like [this](https://code.google.com/p/pywhois/source/browse/pywhois/parser.py?r=ea0e45971cea31656dfa687dd701a201929ad830) and parse the results for the renewal date. That's how I'd do it.

Comment: This looks like a workaroundish "heuristic" method... What is the essential technical difference between normal and "dead" domain?

Comment: Well a dead domain will have no valid nameserver or A records - you could just dig for those and use that as a test/fail thing, otherwise I'm out of ideas. Personally I would just query whois records and parse the results for the renewal date - any date that <= today would be a dead domain

Comment: Appended a domain example that satisfies "expire date > today", but yet still a parked domain.

Comment: Well this wouldn't show parked domains because a parked domain is just a domain with a holding page on it. To check for a holding page you would have to read in the source code of the site and search for obvious strings like "holding page" "parking" "domain" and maybe grab a list of the top 200 hosts and iterate through that.

My solution above is only for domains that have expired or are close to expiring